# Kentico 12 Smart Search Page Crawler Index not working

Tags: kentico

I have a Kentico 12 MVC site where the cms and I guess "client" site are in the same server but separate IIS entries. One is called admin.site.com and the other is called dev.site.com.

I'm trying to implement the Smart Search functionality with a Page Crawler index. The reason I want a Page Crawler index is because my content structure is as follows:

Page Container > Page Type "Product"

Then within "Product" page type, I'm pulling in content from a different part of the content tree using widgets/page builder functionality in the Page tab. The Content tab of that page has very little actual content.

If I use Pages Index and search on that, it only grabs the page types that are in the content widget section of the site, so not the pages that implement the widgets which are the actually live pages on the site. I implemented the Page Crawler index and tried a search preview but literally anything I search comes with no results. Please let me know what details you'd need from me to help, I appreciate any help!

Best,
RP

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-locally-stored-search-indexes/creating-local-search-indexes/defining-local-page-indexes) and especially the note:
"We do not recommend using crawler indexes on MVC content-only sites. The crawler only selects pages from the site's content tree in Kentico, which may not match the actual structure of the website (in many cases, content-only pages only store data and do not represent pages on the live site)."

To achieve your need you will need to create your own crawler code and combine it with [custom search index](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-locally-stored-search-indexes/creating-local-search-indexes/creating-custom-smart-search-indexes).

Comment: I looked at the documentation for creating a custom index and I am a little bit confused. The documentation specifies how to create custom code to go over text files that I guess are the index, but how do I create those txt files in the first place? How would I create a custom crawler to crawl over specific page types and then use the code in the documentation to traverse that custom index I've made? Any starting tips or pointers to more code or anything is much appreciated!

Comment: That is just a sample to see what is needed from Kentico side. The text files are the source of the data for the index. In your case, the source is the front end MVC web site. So, this means you need to create your own crawler as mentioned above, which will crawl the MVC pages to fit your needs and provide the data to the custom index.